# How to connect to remote MySQL server using Socks Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, proxy, mac-osx, mac

I can only connect to a remote server from an `specific IP address (Ubuntu Server)`, this was okay when I was at office but now that I'm working from home I'm stuck.

I have SSH access to the Ubuntu server with this `specific IP address`, so I connected to it using SSH Proxy (which provides local Socks 5 proxy).

So far I have found ways to connect to SSH and FTP (using FileZilla, which supports Socks Proxy)

But I have found no `macOS` MySQL GUI app that supports socks 5 proxy.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use open-ssh local tunneling. You can use option `-L` in command line or `LocalForward` in `~/.ssh/config`

```
ssh -L 33060:mysql_server_ip:3306
```

Then use `localhost:33060` in MySQL clients as `server:port` string.

Another alternative is to use [MySQL Workbench with ssh tunneling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html).